# How to put data in structure into text file using c?

Tags: c, file, struct, text-files, structure

Let's say I have a structure, and it looks like this:

```
struct profile {
    char firstName[15], lastName[15];
    int age, phoneNo;
};
```

and I have a code like this

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fPtr;
    fPtr=fopen("profile.txt", "w");

    printf("\n\nPlease enter your details:");
    struct profile c;
    printf("\n\nEnter your first name: ");
    gets(c.firstName);
    printf("\nEnter your last name: ");
    gets(c.lastName);
    printf("\nEnter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.age);
    printf("Enter your phone number: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.phoneNo);

    fclose(fPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I put the data in this structure into a text file in a way that I will be able to search for specific profiles in the future? Also I'm very new to C so I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain to me if this is possible and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When printing string to a file it is important to remember that the string terminator `'\0'` will result in something that cannot be displayed. So you should avoid writing the strings one by one.

Another possible issue occurs when, using `fwrite` an integer is written... as an integer, meaning that it is stored using 4 bytes containing the actual value. For example the value 72 will be stored as

```
0x48 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

that will be displayed with letter `H` followed by three null characters. So you have to display also numbers as string.

I suggest doing it using `fprintf`. It works like `printf` but it writes to a file instead of `stdout`. In the following example each field is written in a different row, and a double newline ends the current record:

```
fprintf (fPtr, "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n\n",
          firstName, lastName, custID,
          healthHistory, age, phoneNo);
```

---

**Note:** `gets` is **deprecated** as it doesn't perform any string length check. So, for example, if you provide a `firstName` 20 characters long, the exceeding characters will go beyond the size of that field overwriting the following one.  Remember that a char array of size N will contain at most a string `N-1` characters long (one is required by the string terminator).

I suggest using `fgets` instead:

```
fgets (c.firstName, 15, stdin);
```

at most 15 characters will be read,  **including** string terminator  (and including the trailing newline that is sent from command line to terminate the input. You will have [to remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/11336762) in case you don't need it).

Comment: this helped. thank you so much, have a nice day! :) do you know how to remove the trailing new line?

Comment: @cmy Sure! No need to reinvent the wheel: just read this wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/11336762). I'll also edit my answer